# How to Launch a Built In App from within Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'd like to allow a user to manage their WiFi settings from a pinned tile on the start screen. I have set up the tile to pin properly, but I check this in the app's MainPage OnNavigatedTo event. Everything works, except when you launch from the secondary tile you can see the actual application load for a split second before the built in WiFi app is launched. All of the other apps I see with this functionality do not have this issue. I would like to avoid this but I am not sure where to place my code in doing so?

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (fromTile == true) //flag to force the app to close if navigating back from Built in App
            App.Current.Terminate();

        //From Pinned Tile
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey(Constants.Key))
        {
            string _title = null;
            _title = NavigationContext.QueryString[Constants.Key];

            if (_title != null)
            {
                switch (_title)
                {
                    case "Tile_WiFi":
                        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-wifi:"));

                    .. do more stuff ..
                }

                NavigationContext.QueryString.Remove(Constants.Key);
                fromTile = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT*

When placing this code in the constructor I get an System.AccessViolationException on line `NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey(Constants.Key)` stating `Attempt to read or write protected memory.`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following link to achieve your rquirement,

http://abundantcode.com/how-to-launch-the-device-wifi-settings-app-from-the-windows-phone-8-app/

Regards,
Riyaj Ahamed I

Comment: Thanks, although my question isn't about how to launch, rather where to place the code to avoid loading the MainPage before the built in WiFi app. To note, I am using the newer async/await method for launching the WiFi app as compared to the method shown in your link for WP7.

Comment: So you wanted to launch the wifi setttings before the main page launches? If so call the async method which you've implemented before InitializeComponent(); But the OnNavigatedTo() is the one which will run before the page loads.

Comment: Yes, and I have two questions. Can I use `NavigationContext.QueryString` to get the tile's QueryString key and remove the key in a custom method? This was what I was stuck on which is why i put the code in `OnNavigatedTo`. Would you please provide an example? Also, I've noticed OnNavigatedTo runs after the page has been navigated to, which is why I am seeing the MainPage for a split second before being directed to the WiFi app.

Comment: @anonshankar on testing your suggestion for calling an async method before (or after) `InitalizeComponent` in the constructor to get the `QueryString` information and launch the built in WiFi app, `NavigationContext` is `null` and returns an `AccessViolationException`